# Lookup a EJB Bean using JNDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, ejb-3.0

I trying inject a EJB into my class using a InitialContext (JNDI). For this i use a Netbeans insert code mechanism:

[image]

after that Netbeans know witch injection have to use. @EJB annotation or JNDI Lookup. In my Example i have a simple, not managed class and what i want to do is inject a EJB Bean using JNDI. So Netbeans generate code for me as bellow:

[image]

problem is that. When Netbeans generate code for me. He change a web.xml file and add there ejb-local-ref node:

[image]

and when i trying a turn on my web application. I run glasfish and i always get following error:

```
  Exception while deploying the app [mavenproject1-ear] : Error: Unresolved <ejb-link>: mavenproject1-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT#LanguagesFacade
```

i really dont know what to do. Can someone help with this issue. I will greatful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `<ejb-local-ref>` all together. It's defined for dependency injection and this is not your case here since you use JNDI to lookup the bean and set it in langaugeFacade variable. Just remove it and things will be fine.